# Array reduce function for comparing major.minor.patch strings

Tags: javascript, arrays

I came across something weird which I quite did not understand as to why it is working. following code works fine and always return the max version till the patch level. although we are comparing each version string as interger/number. can someone explain me why it is behaving the way it is?

```js
var versionArr = ['4.2.2','4.2.1','3.1.0','3.2.1','3.0.0'];

console.log(versionArr.reduce((acc,item) => acc > item?acc:item));
```

Comment: It won't work once you get into double-digit version numbers. For all intents and purposes, you can think of it sorting alphabetically in this example (though there's a fair bit more nuance to string comparison). However, if you compare `"10"` to `"9"` in the same manner, `9` will be greater because `9 > 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparing strings in Javascript defaults to comparing them by lexicographic order. Coincidentally, lexicographic sorting works pretty closely to how semantic version sorting works. It compares the first character, with larger digits being 'bigger' than smaller digits. If they are different, then the comparison is done. If they are the same, it goes to the second character and compares again. And so on until it comes across two characters that are different.

So comparing `4.2.2` and `4.2.1`, it compares `4` and `4`, sees they are the same, then compares `.` and `.`, sees they are the same, then compares `2` and `2`, sees they are the same, compares `.` and `.` and sees they are the same, then finally compares `2` and `1`, reports that 2 is greater than 1 ergo `4.2.2` is greater than `4.2.1`.

However this won't work for any moderately complicated version. For instance, if once of the components is greater than 9, it breaks. Comparing `10.0.0` and `9.0.0` will report `9.0.0` as the bigger one since 9 is bigger than 1.

Comment: This behaviour is one of the special rules of the javascript relational operators, a list of some of these special rules can be found [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Javascript/Tutorial/0140__Javascript_Relational_Operators.htm).

Comment: Technically the unicode character code, which for english letters, numbers, and basic symbols is equivalent to the ASCII code. For 'special' characters it gets trickier.

Comment: @DavidSampson yes, I actually got the point now. Thank you for that detailed answer. It makes total sense.